# redirecting to insecure content(http) from secure(https)

Tags: apache, http, ssl-certificate

I have some self-signed certificate installed for my application
and so it runs on https.

`https://xyz/redmine`

And i want to call some insecure rather not-signed url from my application.

say,

`http:9292//something/faye`

The browser gives an error  ***running insecure content***

if i make other server to run on secure mode, lets say that it runs on

`https:9292//something/faye`

then unless user adds an exception in browser the url wont be accessible(because i am using self signed certificate)

How can i re-direct or call http from https
or 
Can I add an exception in browser programatically, so that user needs not to add it.

Pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If linking to content on an external site that would be served over http, you can use a protocol neutral URL.

Instead of linking to `http://mysite.com/file.html`, you can link to `//mysite.com/file.html`

Comment: Obviously replace `mysite.com` with the name of the actual site